# Keeping chunk output format in pdf document same as the console output format - Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

The output of the following code chunk is being devided into 2 blocks (figures 1 and 2) in the rendered pdf document, a first block containing the two first columns (Estimate and Std. Error) and another one for the remaining ones (t value and Pr(>|t|)) .
How can the console output format (all columns in one block, figure 3) be kept in the output pdf document?

Code chunk :

````
```{r model1}
lm1=lm(formula=Long.Term.Debt~.,data=donnees[,-c(1:3)])
summary(lm1)
```
````

The rendered output in the pdf document :

[image]

[Fig. 1: A first block containing 2 first columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1KnU.png)

[image]

[Fig. 2: Another block containing 2 remaining columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWdoQ.png)

Desired output :

[image]

[Fig. 3: Console output (one block containing all columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QiYM.png)

I have, fruitlessly, tried increasing the display area of the output and decreasing the font size as follows:

Reducing font size :

````
\tiny
```{r model1}
lm1=lm(formula=Long.Term.Debt~.,data=donnees[,-c(1:3)])
summary(lm1)
```
````

Setting display area size:

````
```{r model1, fig.width=80, fig.height=8}
lm1=lm(formula=Long.Term.Debt~.,data=donnees[,-c(1:3)])
summary(lm1)
```
````

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fig.width=80, fig.height=8` doesn't change the font size of the code since these options serve for figure outputs, not text outputs which you want to show in the PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @CarlosLuisRivera. Indeed, I did that under the hypothesis that the code output is rendered as "some sort of figure" or that "fig.width" and "fig.height" actually parametrise any output display area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `knitr::kable()` and `kableExtra()` to show the summary of the result in a more elegant way. The output of the following code is treated as a table. So, its table number is automatically generated if you are using `bookdown`, too.

````r
```{r summary}
library(knitr)      # for kable()
library(knitrExtra) # for further customisation of the kable() output 
library(magrittr)   # for the pipe %>%, press "Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + m"

kable(summary(lm1)$coefficient[, 0:4], # by 0:4, you can select the columns from variable names to p-values 
      digits = 2,                      # You can reduce the digit number
      booktabs = TRUE,                 # If false, you will get a lattice-like table
      caption = 'Coefficients (2 not defined because of sigularities)'
      ) %>% 
kable_styling(font_size = 7)           # You can change the font size here
```
````

Comment: Thank you @CarlosLuisRivera for the answer and additional features. This way though, the coefficients' significance stars are not printed. Of course, if they are necessary, a vector of these can be created based on the p-values, but I realised that the initial problem was due to the lengthy column names of the data frame (as for Equity...subsidiary) so renaming the columns fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can change `kable(summary(lm1)$coefficient[, 0:4])` to `kable(summary(lm1)$coefficient[, 0:5])`. Does this show the stars?

Comment: I tried indeed ( also tried `kable(summary(lm1)$coefficients)` ) but it doesn't work. By checking the structures `str(summary(lm1))` and `str(summary(lm1)$coefficients)` , significance stars don't seem to be an attribute of the summary or coefficients objects.